# In what location does Tiki store articles: in the file system or in the MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, wiki, filenames, site-structure

I have a dump of the directory structure from an old Tiki website from around 2010 that is no longer up.  I would like to view the raw text of the articles but am unable to locate any files that appear to be articles after browsing the directory structure.  Where does Tiki store user articles in the file system?  I found `lib/articles/artlib.php` and `lib/articles/index.php`, but nothing appeared to be user added in there. Perhaps there were no articles, if so, how can I confirm that?

Alternatively, are the articles stored in the MySQL database and not stored as textual files?  If in the db, is there an easy way to browse them?  I'd rather not create a complete Tiki site and try to map these old file system into it only to discover that there was no useful content, so how can I judge how much content was actually added?  Thus far, I've found one image file in `temp/CRW_0075.jpg` that was added to the site, but that is the only sign of content I've located thus far.

My ultimate goal here is to assess if there is any useful information in this Tiki and if so, to extract it into a private MediaWiki I am helping to create.

---

Note that this is Tikiwiki v3.0 the README in the top level directory shows:

> Tiki! The wiki with a lot of features!
>   Version 3.0
>
> DOCUMENTATION
>
> - The documentation for 3.0 version is under construction on >http://doc.tikiwiki.org.
>     You're encouraged to contribute.
> - It is highly recommended that you refer to the online documentation:
> - http://doc.tikiwiki.org/Installation for a setup guide
> - Notes about this release are accessible from http://tikiwiki.org/ReleaseNotes30
> - Tikiwiki has an active IRC channel, #tikiwiki on irc.freenode.net
>
> INSTALLATION
>
> - There is a file INSTALL in this directory with notes on how to setup and
>     configure Tiki. Again, see http://doc.tikiwiki.org/Installation for the latest install help.
>
> UPGRADES
>
> - Read the online instructions if you want to upgrade your Tiki from a previous release http://doc.tikiwiki.org/Upgrade
>
> COPYRIGHT
>
> Copyright (c) 2002-2009, Luis Argerich, Garland Foster, Eduardo Polidor, et. al.
>   All Rights Reserved. See copyright.txt for details and a complete list of authors.
>   Licensed under the GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE. See license.txt for details.
>
> ... Have fun!
>
> Note to Tiki developers: update this text through release.php.

Comment: Note that this was [previously asked about Twiki](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77428/where-does-twiki-store-articles-in-the-file-system-or-in-the-mysql-database), but we don't have an answer for TikiWiki yet.

Comment: Nearly every wiki stores the data in a database. In nearly every database system, this is stored outside of the filesystem is the program. Who created the directory dump?

Comment: @DanielF I created the dump using `rsync` with an `ssh` connection to the remote machine to get all files in the tree recursively.

Comment: All? Or just the webroot

Comment: @DanielF I got the webroot, but could acquire others if that is where the data resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to export the mysql table that it is stored in.

Open a SSH connection to your server.

Sign in to mysql with `mysql - u [username]  -p`. Enter your password when prompted. Type `show databases`. Choose the database the seems the right one. Type `use [database name ]`. Type `show tables`. Remember the table that appears relevant. Now, exit mysql with `exit`.

Type `mysqldump - u [username] - p [table name that you remembered]  > exportedTable.sql`. Enter your password when prompted. The file exportable.sql has the table's data, and you can download it over sftp/ftp.

If the table doesn't have the right data, try again, but pick a different database or table.